# Add watermark to fancybox only for gallery items and not for non gallery items

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, fancybox-2

I have a page that contains a FancyBox image gallery and some single FancyBox elements like div's.
I need to have a watermark on my gallery items so I used the example from FancyBox page http://jsfiddle.net/w5gQS/

```
beforeShow: function () { $('<div class="watermark"></div>').prependTo( $.fancybox.inner );
```

But that prepended the watermark div to all FancyBox elements including the single ones.

**My question:**
is it possible to add watermark only to the gallery items and if it is how can it be done (the cleaner the method the better)?

P.S. using FancyBox v2.1.5

best regards

Comment: I would venture to say that you should be able to add some osrt of a class to the .prependTo part of the above code that identifies galleries only.  Add a class of gallery to your galleries and include that in your function.

Comment: the thing is I am new to javascript and I dont really know how to do that.
Also with the current script the watermark is added in the same div that the content(image or div) but before it so the content would be on top.
Everything would be simple if I would be able to edit the content of the fancybox popup but that part is generated with javascript of fancybox

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve that easily evaluating how many elements are in the `group` so if there are more than one then is *gallery*, otherwise is a single element.

Using the code on the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/w5gQS/) of reference, tweak it this way :

```
$(".fancybox").fancybox({
    beforeShow: function () {
        /* Add watermark to gallery elements only */
        if ( this.group.length > 1 ) {
            $('<div class="watermark"></div>')
                .bind("contextmenu", function (e) {
                return false; /* Disables right click */
            }).prependTo($.fancybox.inner);
        }
    }
});
```

See forked **[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/ttsnX/1/)**

Comment: thanks a lot JFK works great, just in time to meet my deadline, you saved me :)